# WCF Callback notify user interface

Tags: wpf, multithreading, wcf, callback

I have a wcf callback service and the following scenario:

A client send a request to the service, and modify the color of a rectangle in the database, the service notifies it that the color has changed, and I want now in the callback notified method, to color the rectangle that was clicked with the chosen color:

Here is the method which is invoked when I click on rectangle

```
private void ChangeRectangleState_Single(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Path mc = (Path)sender;
    String name = mc.Name;

    flag_macaz = colorClass.getRectangleColor(mc.Name+"_a",rectangleServiceClient);
    ColorClass.changeRectangleColor(flag_rectangle,macazServiceClient,mc.Name+"_a");
}

public void RectangleServiceCallback_ClientNotified(objectsender,Rectangle NotifiedEventArgs e)
{
   String name = e.RectangleName;
   object wantedNode_a = Window.FindName(e.RectangleName);
   Path rectangle = wantedNode_a as Path;
   if (e.RectangleColor == 1)
   {
       rectangle.fill=...
   }
   else
        if (e.RectangleColor == 0)
   {
       rectangle.fill=...
   }
}
```

But I get the error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

I have tried the idea from http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher but the client get blocked.

Does anybody has other idea?

Comment: Why are you using callback in scenario where request response is enough?

Comment: I want to notifty other clients about the new color.I have an application with traffic lights.I want when a user change the light of a traffic light, other user to see that, to be notified about that.

Answer (score 1):

The WCF thread can't call the UI thread directly.

You'll need to fire an event from the WCF thread and subscribe to it in the UI thread. Then in your UI event handler have something like:

```
    this.albumArt.InvokeIfRequired(() => this.SetBackgroundColor());
```

where `InvokeIfRequired` is an extension method:

```
public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Control control, Action action)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.Invoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please detail me, I am begginer in wcf and wpf and I don't understand.Thank you

Comment: @Annymmor - do you know about events and event handlers?

Comment: Yes a little.I know that when an event is invoked he call the handler which invoke all the methods associated to it.I put in the ui a method which is called when the service notifies the client.But the clients get blocked